# How to select a part of formula in formula in R?

Tags: r, parsing, formula

Suppose I have a following formula:

```
fr <- formula(y~myfun(x)+z)
```

Given object `fr` is there a function in R which returns `myfun(x)`? I've written my own function (code below) which basically does what I need, but maybe there is some standard way of doing that?

The code for my function:

```
selectmds <- function(expr,funcn) {
    if(length(expr)>2) {
        a <- expr[[2]]
        b <- expr[[3]]
        if(length(a)>1) {
            if(as.name(a[[1]])==funcn) {
                if(length(grep(funcn,all.names(b)))>0) {
                    return(list(a,selectmds(b,funcn)))
                }
                else return(list(a))
            }
        }
        if(length(b)>1) {
            if(as.name(b[[1]])==funcn) {
                if(length(grep(funcn,all.names(a)))>0) {
                    return(list(b,selectmds(a,funcn)))
                }
                else return(list(b))
            }
        }
        for(i in 2:length(expr)) {
            if(length(grep(funcn,all.names(expr[[i]])))>0)return(selectmds(expr[[i]],funcn))
        }
    }
    return(NULL)
}
```

Here are several examples:

```
> selectmds(formula(y~myfun(x)+z),"myfun")
[[1]]
myfun(x)


> unlist(selectmds(formula(y~myfun(x)+z+myfun(zz)),"myfun"))
[[1]]
myfun(zz)

[[2]]
myfun(x)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure this is best, but you can do it by:

```
f <- function(fm, fun) {
  l <- as.list(attr(terms(fm), "variables"))[-1]
  l[grep(fun, l)]
}
```

then,

```
> f(formula(y~myfun(x)+z),"myfun")
[[1]]
myfun(x)

> f(formula(y~myfun(x)+z+myfun(zz)),"myfun")
[[1]]
myfun(x)

[[2]]
myfun(zz)
```

Comment: Pretty close to what was I looking for. Parsing formulas is fun, but it is nice to have someone else to parse them for me:)

Comment: I wonder: perhaps there's a way to return the definition of `f` as a string object, i.e. `fname <- "formula(y~myfun(stuff)+z)"` . Then you can just do a `grep` for everything between "~" and ")" .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I need the stuff in parenthesis too. Converting formula to string and using grep is a not a good idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `specials` argument to `terms` that allows you to flag named functions in the formula for extraction by position.

So, you can write

```
selectmds<-function(form,fn) {
  tt<-terms(form,specials=fn);
  idx<-attr(tt,"specials");
  v<-as.list(attr(tt,"variables"))[-1];
  unlist(lapply(idx,function(i) v[i]))
}
```

Then your testcases give

```
> selectmds(formula(y~myfun(x)+z),"myfun")
$myfun
myfun(x)

> selectmds(formula(y~myfun(x)+z+myfun(zz)),"myfun")
$myfun1
myfun(x)

$myfun2
myfun(zz)
```

But, you can also do

```
> selectmds(formula(y~myfun(x)+myfun(x2)+z+yourfun(zz)),c("myfun","yourfun"))
$myfun1
myfun(x)

$myfun2
myfun(x2)

$yourfun
yourfun(zz)
```

Where you could strike the `unlist` to have this nested by named function instead.